# reaching python with R

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, rstudio

I am trying to install tensorflow in `Rstudio`, when I run `install_tensorflow()`, I get

```
Error: Prerequisites for installing TensorFlow not available.

Execute the following at a terminal to install the prerequisites:

$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

But `virtualenv` is already installed.

I don't konw much thing about python.

I am using `OSX`.

`which python` outputs

```
`/home/name/.pyenv/shims/python`
```

but when going to the `python` console, I get

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Dec  3 2015, 00:46:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/home/name/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/bin/python'
```

`system("python --version")` in `Rstudio` outputs

```
Python 2.7.10
```

SO I tried to put in my `.Rprofile` this

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("/home/name/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/bin/python", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))
```

or this

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("/home/name/.pyenv/shims/python", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))
```

Besides, I see that the `tensorflow` packages is indeed installed

```
/home/name/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Someone has an idea ?

UPDATE:

Since python `tensorflow` package is already installed in my system, located under `/home/name/.pyenv/somepath/`, I tried to run some tensorflow function directly inside `RStudio` and I got this

```
Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
 /usr/bin/python

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.
```

knowing that running `Sys.getenv()` in `RStudio` gives the correct path

PATH                       `/home/name/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/bin/python:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin`

UPDATE 2

Now, I think I am beginning to locate the problem. I forced `RStudio` to use the version of `python` that I get when I run `sys.executable
    '/home/name/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/bin/python'`

So `use_python("/home/name/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/bin/python")`

Now, when I run some `tensorflow` function I get

Error: Python module tensorflow was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

```
python:         /usr/bin/python
libpython:      /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib
pythonhome:     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
version:        2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]
numpy:          /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy
numpy_version:  1.8.1
tensorflow:     [NOT FOUND]
```

It seems `Rstudio` doesn't take into account the version I want it to use

Solution : To find where the problem came from and how to tackle it, get [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759252/force-python-version-for-rstudio/45759900#45759900)

Comment: `sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv` means that you have to update/upgrade virtual env so try the command line first

Comment: @OrhanYazar sure that's what I did and it did not work

Comment: @OrhanYazar when I run this command again I get `Requirement already up-to-date: virtualenv in ./.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: Are you trying to run a python package on rstudio ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar yes I am running `install_tensorflow()` of the `R` `tensorflow` package inside `Rstudio`

Comment: You want to install tensorflow to use it on Rstudio ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar exactely ! besides, I have just updated my post and I think it is interesting

Comment: @OrhanYazar I have just added a supplementary interesting UPDATE, I think I am beginning to locate the issue

Comment: Can you go to python console and just try `import tensorflow` ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar I get no output, it seems to be correctly installed

Comment: @OrhanYazar the problem is that `Rstudio` does not access to the correct version of python. AI tried to force it but it does not work

Comment: Did you installed tensorflow on R ? I mean did you do `install.packages("tensorflow")` and then `library(tensorflow)`

`install_tensorflow()`

Comment: @OrhanYazar exactely and I also installed `tensorflow` on my `osx`

Comment: Are you working with a conda virtual env ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar no and I don't know what it is ;)

Comment: How do you build your virtual env then ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar sorry I almost know nothing about python. Once a time, I installed `virtualenv` following some documentations without really carrying about what I was doing. What do you suggest me to do ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar besides I deleted my update 3 because fro some reason I  get again the error output of UPDATE 2

Comment: Can you give me the link of the doc your using to install tensorflow on Rstudio please ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar here it is `https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation.html#installation_methods`

Comment: Did you check the custom installation ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar I think I have a central issue that maybe related. So I created a specific new `SO` questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759252/force-python-version-for-rstudio

Comment: I saw it, the probleme is not the package but something else

Comment: @OrhanYazar sure but why can't I force Rstudio to get the right python version ? and why do the output of `sys.executable` differ when I am in python console and when I run it from `Rstudio` ?

Comment: Try setting this in your **.Rprofile**: Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("/home/name/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/bin/python", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":")) to tel R where it is in your system directly

Comment: @sconfluentus thank you, that's what I did some times ago and it did not work !

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
install_tensorflow("virtualenv", envname="myenv")
```

this will create a new python virtualenv environment.