# force python version for Rstudio

Tags: python, r, rstudio

I have some weird issue regarding getting the right python version inside `Rstudio`.

In the python console, I get

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Dec  3 2015, 00:46:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/home/name/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/bin/python'
```

In `Rstudio`

sys <- import("sys")
sys$executable

throws this

```
"/usr/bin/python"
```

If I force

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("/home/name/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/bin/python2.7", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))
```

I get the same result. Someone has an idea ?

Comment: Can you try this ? `use_python("/home/name/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/bin/python")` and/or this `Sys.setenv(TENSORFLOW_PYTHON="/home/name/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/bin/python")`

Comment: @OrhanYazar sure I tried this but it didn't change anything !

Comment: Are you using the `reticulate` package? If so, this might help you set up: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/versions.html

Comment: @OrhanYazar I found the solution !

Comment: @meenaparam I have jsut find the solution, see my answer

Comment: @OrhanYazar I come back to you because indeed it worked once and then now it still sucks. I tried to reproduce from the history the exact same commands but it is not working anymore

Comment: @meenaparam I come back to you because indeed it worked once and then now it still sucks. I tried to reproduce from the history the exact same commands but it is not working anymore – user2478159 just now

Comment: @user2478159 Did you look at the link on `reticulate` in the earlier comments? It talks you through using different versions of Python in RStudio, which sounds like what you want to do.

Comment: @OrhanYazar now I have it for sure, see my response ;) besides, thanks so much for your help

Comment: @meenaparam now I have it for sure, see my response ;) besides, thanks so much for your help